# Any workaround to show the People Picker inside the built-in Edit & New forms

Tags: development, custom-form, form, edit-form, newform

I am working on an Issue tracking list inside SP 2013, where I have associate the AssignTo field with a security group. but currently inside the built-in Edit & New forms I cannot select the AssignTo users from the “People Picker” dialog box instead I need to autocomplete the users, while if I create a custom edit or custom new forms the People Picker will be available.

Now I do not want to use  custom forms because I need features such as :- automatically add new fields to the forms when I add a new field to the content type, where this feature is only available on the built-in forms unlike custom forms.

I know that having People Picker inside the build-in new & edit forms are not available by default. so my question if there are any workarounds ?, as our customers want to have People Pickers and at the same time they want the ability to automatically add a field to the forms once they add a field to the content type.
Can anyone advice if there is any workaround regarding this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that is (somewhat) commonly known and often suggested is to create a new New/Edit form through SharePoint Designer as that will add the People Picker with the "browse" and "check name" buttons.

Comment: but if i create custom edit OR custom New forms this will miss the feature to automatically add new fields to these forms if i add a new field to the content type,, which i need as i will be managing 30 sub sites..